# EhCache: timeToLiveSeconds in a Self Populating Cache

Tags: ehcache

I am planning on using a SelfPopulatingCache in my application component, as it supports read-through and what seems like a backing cache for refreshes.

However, I am a little bemused by the **timeToLiveSeconds** configuration. This is my test configuration:

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache name="myCache" maxElementsInMemory="50000" overflowToDisk="false"
    eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="2"/>

</ehcache>
```

In my unit tests, I perform the following:

- Verify there are 2 entries in my cache
- Sleep for 3 seconds
- However, after the sleep there are still 2 entries in my cache.

Per other posts online (and not the documentation), when I next perform a read, my entries should be evicted.

However, instead the CacheEntryFactory will be invoked, and a null Element will be added to the cache for my expired elements.

Is there any way to configure this to instead perform a full eviction when timeToLiveSeconds expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe "full eviction" can only happen if there was a separate expiry thread. Unfortunately, for in-memory entries there's no such thing. Quoting [Ehcache FAQ](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#why-is-there-an-expiry-thread-for-the-diskstore-but-not-for-the-memorystore):

> Because the MemoryStore has a fixed maximum number of elements, it
>   will have a maximum memory use equal to the number of elements
>   multiplied by the average size. When an element is added beyond the
>   maximum size, the LRU element gets pushed into the DiskStore. While we
>   could have an expiry thread to expire elements periodically, it is far
>   more efficient to only check when we need to. The tradeoff is higher
>   average memory use. The expiry thread keeps the DiskStore clean. There
>   is hopefully less contention for the DiskStore's locks because
>   commonly used values are in the MemoryStore. We mount our DiskStore on
>   Linux using RAMFS so it is using OS memory. While we have more of this
>   than the 2GB 32-bit process size limit, it is still an expensive
>   resource. The DiskStore thread keeps it under control. If you are
>   concerned about CPU utilization and locking in the DiskStore, you can
>   set the diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds to a high number, such as 1
>   day. Or, you can effectively turn it off by setting the
>   diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds to a very large value.